# forwarding windows applications to linux

Tags: windows, forwarding, rdp

I'm looking to implement a solution to forward Windows applications to a Linux box.
XMing will let me do the reverse - ie: forward Linux applications to a Windows box.

The wikipedia article for RDP claims that something like this is supported but I couldn't find anything in the API.

To avoid confusion, I am not looking to share the entire desktop. If you have 2 applications running on a Windows host, I'd like the Linux client to be able to see and interact with both applications irrespective of whether they are minimized or overlapping on the Windows host.

Any pointers to existing open source software would also be much appreciated!

Comment: belongs on superuser.com

Comment: @Daniel: superuser?  He says he's looking to "implement" a solution and talks about searching APIs...?  Links to existing solutions were requested for reference.  It's still a programming question, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check out seamlessRDP (http://www.cendio.com/seamlessrdp/) and rdesktop (www.rdesktop.org)

Guide on how to use them together
http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/124908

I think this should go to the superuser side too.

Comment: seamlessrdp and rdesktop are great tips, thianks! seamlessrdp doesn't seem to be working as advertised on Win7 but it is a good place to start nevertheless.